# Display tabbed message in HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, css

I want to generate an HTML file using python that takes the following message from a file.

**How it looks in a text editor:**

```
MessageOne = Message {
---- requestId ---- ---- ---- ---- Request, 
---- responseTimeDate--- ---- ---- Somerandomvalue,
---- responseDate-- ---- ---- ---- Data {
---- ---- dataString---- ---- ---- ---- BlehBlehBleh
---- }
}
```

*Note: (`----`) are tabs.*

The HTML of course does't understand the tabs so I replace `\t` with 4 x `nbsp;` but the spacing gets messed up because of the tab behaviour.

**How it looks in HTML:**

```
MessageOne = Message {
---- requestId ---- ---- ---- ---- Request, 
---- responseTimeDate ---- ---- ---- Somerandomvalue,
---- responseDate ---- ---- ---- ---- Data {
---- ---- dataString ---- ---- ---- ---- BlehBlehBleh
---- }
}
```

*Note: Each dash (`-`) and spaces represent `nbsp;`*

Is there any way I can align it properly in HTML? (I have thought about using tables but would't work due to this structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your tabs to spaces, and using <pre> and </pre> tags in your HTML?  Does that do what you need?  I don't think you'll need &nbsp; this way.

Comment: @dstromberg Thanks! I didn't have any knowledge about <pre> tag. It seems to be working but in some cases, due to the HTML char size difference (I'm guessing), it seems to shows 1 less or 1 extra tab. Any idea how I can dodge that?

Comment: After a bit of research, I found out that using monospace font family solves the problem with character width. Thanks!